Why the severity in my alert appear "warning" if I configured "ERROR" as message?
When I configured the message in the alerts, not work
{
  "textPayload": "2024-06-06T12:29:09.060682Z\**twarning**\tenvoy config external/envoy/source/common/config/grpc_stream.h:175\tStreamAggregatedResources gRPC config stream to xds-grpc closed: 8, request rate limit exceeded: rate: Wait(n=1) would exceed context deadline (previously 14, error reading from server: EOF since 0s ago)\tthread=28",
  "insertId": "$ID",
  "resource": {
    "type": "k8s_container",
    "labels": {
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2024-06-06T12:29:09.060770007Z",
  "severity": **"ERROR"**,
  "labels": {

What's happening? Did I do something wrong?
I configure specifically the message as ERROR and I would like to see it.

Welcome to StackOverflow.   When you say "I confgured the message in the alerts" ... what does that mean?  Can you elaborate?   You then said "it did not work" ... that's too vague, can you improve the phrasing.  How did you "configure" the message as ERROR?  What do you mean by "I would like to see it".

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
